# Wordpress database connection

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress business to let user register into your website. I know that wp-config.php file is used to connect to the db. But in my themes folder do I need to connect to the database again as in the code below.
**connect.php**

```
mysql_connect('localhost','xxxxx','xxxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxxx');
```

**init.php**

```
require 'connect.php';
```

**registration.php**

```
include 'init.php';
```

I have used `$connect_error = "Database error!";` in my connect.php file and key in a a wrong host and username, but it doesn't prompt me with error message. I think it doesn't connected to my database.

Comment: What's not working? Also, Wordpress has a DB wrapper: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: So what you're saying is I don't need to include all these connect.php and init.php files, I can straight away use $wpdb in my registration.php file?

Comment: Probably. It won't let you interact with databases other than the Wordpress database, but I think you can create your own table inside of it.

Comment: Do I need to include the wp-config.php and wp-db.php file before I use the $wpdb?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to connect to wordpress database from your own theme
so that whenever user will visit site they can see form which can be validate
Process is as follows :
1.To let user register into website there is need to create form on frontend

2.Create your own theme http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm

3.Add Subscribe table to your user database with columns as name, username, password, email_id

4.In index.php file add following code to that file to connect database

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "INSERT INTO Subscribe(name, username, password, email_id)VALUES('$name', '$uname', '$pswd', '$email')" );
```

The $wpdb object is not limited to the default tables created by WordPress. 
It can be used to read data from any table in the WordPress database such as custom plugin table